# Is anybody mainteinting Chromium-embedded pre-built for Windows?

Tags: chromium-embedded

I am looking to embed Chromium into my Windows application, but I do not want to build from source, I would prefer DLL pre-built by some body else. The problem is that I cannot find anything like that. Please help (if that's possible at all)

(In case you wonder why I do not want to build myself.. I use Windows XP 32 bit, and Chromium documentation website states 32-bit host OS is not support for builds (anymore). And that's just the first stone on the way. I will need many dependencies, read a lot of docs and do some configurations. Previously I have been building V8 alone, and that took me days to figure. I would really like to avoid stepping into those waters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Chromium Embedded Framework 3 Builds](http://cefbuilds.com)

Comment: Hosted and maintained by the Web Engine Team at Adobe. Releases for Windows Mac and Linux, all 32-64 bits.